# Dynamically separate the y-Coordinate of Charts

Tags: algorithm, math, charts

I'm trying to figure out how Google Charts is able to dynamically split the y-Coordinate to achieve the following outcome:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

There are basically two questions that I have.
1) How to dynamically calculate the suited number of y-coordinate separators based on the given ticker prices. 
2) How to calculate the steps between these lines.

A similar question has been asked before: [Calculating chart for YAxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742420/calculating-chart-for-yaxis)

But this question is specific to Google's approach of solving the problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "split the Y coordinates"? Are you talking about the value range for the Y axis, i.e. the minimum/maximum value shown on the axis and the intervals for labels? I assume the min/max values are calculated by looking at the highest and lowest chart value and rounding to a ceiling or floor factor. The intervals are then calculated according to the difference between min and max.

Comment: Correct, but in these example they must use some formula to decide how many horizontal separation lines to draw. I don't quite see the correlation between the datapoints and the number of horizontal separations.

Comment: It looks like they don't decide for a number of ticks but for their spacing. The first chart uses a spacing of 10, the second one of 1. So there are probably some pre-defined spacings and they use the one that works best (produces an adequate number of ticks maybe).

Comment: A quick survey indicates that they're using a 1,2,5 scheme. Which is to say that they compute the spacing based on 5 lines, then multiply the spacing by a power of 10 so that it's between 1 and 10. Then round to the nearest of 1, 2, 5, or 10, and divide by the same power of 10, to get the spacing.

Comment: See also [nice label algorithm for charts with minimum ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506881/nice-label-algorithm-for-charts-with-minimum-ticks/16363437#16363437)

Comment: @JohanC Thanks a lot, that is pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The number of intervals on the Y axis and its step values are derived from the difference between the minimum and maximum axis value.

Take the difference between floor/ceiling rounded min/max and divide it by either 1, 5 or 10 (or multiples of 5 and 10) to arrive at the interval steps. The number of intervals will differ, but the magnitude of 1, 5 or 10 or its multiples will provide pleasant intervals for the Y axis labels.

In the first example, the difference is 100 points, so it's been divides by 5 to arrive at five intervals, each number ending in a pleasant 0.

In the second example, the difference is 4 points, so it's been divided by 1 to arrive at four intervals.